# JQuery disable form and change div contents

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Im using the following ajax code to submit data from a form to a servlet and then have the servlet send data back (havent quite mastered this part yet).

Side question, the variable id is obtained from the .jsp file by using

```
`<script> var id = '${id}' </script>`
```

Is there a better way to access this variable directly from inside a .js file that is loaded on the page ? It works as is but it seems messy.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.doAction').click(function () {
        var rel = parseInt($('.doAction:checked').attr('rel'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                rating: rel,
                itemID: id
            },
            url: 'Ratings',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML form code is

```
<div id=holder>
    <div id="rating">
    Rating
        <form id="ratingsform" name="ratingsform">
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="1" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="2" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="3" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="4" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="5" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what i want to happen is when a radio button is selected, the form is disabled so that new radio buttons can't be pressed (so the servlet cant be spammed to death). When the servlet responds to the ajax post call, I would like to change the contents of the div "rating" to display the updated ratings and remove the ability to vote i.e remove the radio buttons / form. I have the server side code working except for figuring out how to return the values required which hopefully is pretty straight forward.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well check my comments to understand the change

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var id = '${id}' // you can have it here
    $('.doAction').click(function () {
        var rel = $('.doAction:checked').attr('rel'); // you need not parse to int because it will always string in parameter
        $('.doAction').prop('disabled', true); // to disable radio button
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html', // change this since your servlet response is html not json
            cache: false,
            data: {
                rating: rel,
                itemID: id
            },
            url: 'Ratings',
            success: function (data) {
                   $('#rating').html(data); // assuming response as {"rating" : 4.4} 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The disable function works perfectly thanks. Placing var id = '${id}' inside the .js file in any position doesnt seem to work. it just sets id equal to the string ${id} not its value on the .jsp. Also, $('#rating').html(data.rating); doesnt seem to do anything. In my servlet i have PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); String message = "<h2> " + rating + "</h2>"; out.print(message); where rating is the desired value. I can see in firebug that the response is recieved but its not clearing the form from the div and adding the response. Any ideas ?

Comment: change dataType: 'json' to dataType: 'html' and 
$('#rating').html(data.rating); to $('#rating').html(data); .. updated the answer..

Comment: Still doesnt do anything. response gets recieved in firebug but doesnt display

Answer (score 0):

In your server-side scripting, you need to `print` the data you would like sent back, then call it through the `success` function of the `$.ajax` object:

```
// Other AJAX...
success:function(msg){
    $('#rating').html(msg);
}
// Other AJAX
```

I'm not the most familier with JSP, however I believe the command is something like `out.print()`.

Answer (score 0):

// Your js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.doAction').live('click',function () {
        // If we click then it is checked
        var rel = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
        // The id of the input hidden
        var id = $('#theID').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                rating: rel,
                itemID: id
            },
            url: 'Ratings',
            success: function (data) {
                // Displays the data returned by your servlet
                $('#rating').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

// HTML

```
<div id=holder>
    <div id="rating">
    Rating
        <form id="ratingsform" name="ratingsform">
            <input type="hidden" name="theID" value='${id}'/>
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="1" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="2" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="3" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="4" />
            <input class="doAction" type="radio" name="ra1" rel="5" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the server returns data? How is this returned? I would to this:

```
        ...
        success: function (data) {
             $("#ratings").html('<div class="rating '+rel+'stars"></div>');
        }
        ...
```

And create 2 classes, one called `rating` and 5 more called 1,2,3,4,5stars, that would work.

Good luck!